# Matrix operations in Mirror.js (Three js)

Tags: javascript, three.js, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I'm working on creating water in three.js and so far I have not seen any water examples in three.js implementing both reflection and refraction, but if you do, please link.
At the moment I'm working at building on top of Mirror.js by Slayvin
https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_mirror.html

My plan was to use a second rendertarget to render the refractiontexture in a similar fashion as the reflection and then blend the two textures in the shader.

Right now I have a temporary refraction rendertarget that I use for the blending, which works. However, this temporary refraction is horribly distorted at the moment since I'm not applying the correct matrix multiplications to the texture. It should be waaay easier than the mirror I think, but this does not work as I thought it would. How do I know what the initial texturematrix should be set to?

```
this.updateMatrixWorld();
this.camera.updateMatrixWorld();

// Update the texture matrix
this.textureMatrixRefraction.set( 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5,
                        0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5,
                        0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5,
                        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

this.textureMatrixMirror.multiply( this.camera.projectionMatrix );
this.textureMatrixMirror.multiply( this.camera.matrixWorldInverse );
```

I'm trying to figure out how the matrix operations for the mirror works since I am missing something very important. I tried to just make a simpler version from this which is the code above. The caps comments in the code are mine, so if you could explain some of my questionmarks that would be great.

```
THREE.Water.prototype.updateTextureMatrixMirror = function () {

    //UPDATE TO CURRENT WORLD AND CAMERA FOR MIRROROBJECT
this.updateMatrixWorld();
this.camera.updateMatrixWorld();
//COPY VALUES FROM WORLD AND CAMERA, GETTING TRANSFORMATIONS IN WORLD
this.mirrorWorldPosition.setFromMatrixPosition( this.matrixWorld );
this.cameraWorldPosition.setFromMatrixPosition( this.camera.matrixWorld );

this.rotationMatrix.extractRotation( this.matrixWorld );
//SET NORMAL AND APPLY ROTATION
this.normal.set( 0, 0, 1 );
this.normal.applyMatrix4( this.rotationMatrix );
//CREATE NEW CAMERA VIEW, THIS IS ONLY RELEVANT FOR THE REFLECTION
var view = this.mirrorWorldPosition.clone().sub( this.cameraWorldPosition );
view.reflect( this.normal ).negate();   //tHIS IS NOT NEEDED FOR REFRACTION?
view.add( this.mirrorWorldPosition );

this.rotationMatrix.extractRotation( this.camera.matrixWorld );
//SET LOOKAT... NOT REALLY GRASPING WHAT IT CHANGES?
this.lookAtPosition.set( 0, 0, -1 );
this.lookAtPosition.applyMatrix4( this.rotationMatrix );
this.lookAtPosition.add( this.cameraWorldPosition );
//TARGET, ALSO TROUBLY UNDERSTANDING WHAT IT CHANGES
var target = this.mirrorWorldPosition.clone().sub( this.lookAtPosition );
target.reflect( this.normal ).negate();  //WHAT HAPPENS HERE??
target.add( this.mirrorWorldPosition );

this.up.set( 0, -1, 0 ); //CHANGING TO NEG Y 
this.up.applyMatrix4( this.rotationMatrix );
this.up.reflect( this.normal ).negate(); // IS THIS NEEDED? 

//MIRRORCAMERA COPIES THE GENERATED VALUES AND UPDATES
this.mirrorCamera.position.copy( view );
this.mirrorCamera.up = this.up;
this.mirrorCamera.lookAt( target );

this.mirrorCamera.updateProjectionMatrix();
this.mirrorCamera.updateMatrixWorld();
this.mirrorCamera.matrixWorldInverse.getInverse( this.mirrorCamera.matrixWorld ); // IS THIS NEEDED FOR REFRACTION?
//THIS IS WHERE THE MAGIC HAPPENS, TEXTURE MATRIX IS UPDATED
// Update the texture matrix
this.textureMatrixMirror.set( 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5,
                        0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5,
                        0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5,
                        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
//USE THE GENERATED MIRRORCAMERA TO GET MATRIX MULTIPLICATIONS
this.textureMatrixMirror.multiply( this.mirrorCamera.projectionMatrix ); 
this.textureMatrixMirror.multiply( this.mirrorCamera.matrixWorldInverse ); 

// AS I UNDERSTAND, THIS PART DEALS WITH THE CLIPPING USING OBLIQUE FRUSTUMS
// Now update projection matrix with new clip plane, implementing code from: http://www.terathon.com/code/oblique.html
// Paper explaining this technique: http://www.terathon.com/lengyel/Lengyel-Oblique.pdf
this.waterPlane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint( this.normal, this.mirrorWorldPosition );
this.waterPlane.applyMatrix4( this.mirrorCamera.matrixWorldInverse );

this.clipPlane.set( this.waterPlane.normal.x, this.waterPlane.normal.y, this.waterPlane.normal.z, this.waterPlane.constant );

var q = new THREE.Vector4();
var projectionMatrix = this.mirrorCamera.projectionMatrix;

q.x = ( Math.sign( this.clipPlane.x ) + projectionMatrix.elements[ 8 ] ) / projectionMatrix.elements[ 0 ];
q.y = ( Math.sign( this.clipPlane.y ) + projectionMatrix.elements[ 9 ] ) / projectionMatrix.elements[ 5 ];
q.z = - 1.0;
q.w = ( 1.0 + projectionMatrix.elements[ 10 ] ) / projectionMatrix.elements[ 14 ];

// Calculate the scaled plane vector
var c = new THREE.Vector4();
c = this.clipPlane.multiplyScalar( 2.0 / this.clipPlane.dot( q ) );

// Replacing the third row of the projection matrix
projectionMatrix.elements[ 2 ] = c.x;
projectionMatrix.elements[ 6 ] = c.y;
projectionMatrix.elements[ 10 ] = c.z + 1.0 - this.clipBias;
projectionMatrix.elements[ 14 ] = c.w;
```

**Update:** So I've managed to get a half descent visual result, however, there are several bugs and I know I' not creating the refraction texture properly because of the faulty matrix transformations. Also I'm struggling to get a nice flow on the offset for the dudv-map that I've implemented, at the moment I'm using a sine-function but this lead to a swaying motion and looks very unnatural, though it avoids a "jump cut" of just looping the rippleMoveFactor with remain of division value. See the current result and full code at: [Demo](http://liuloppan.github.io/watershader)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some explanations:

The 'lookatPosition' part seems useless, but it allows me to get a position 1 unit away (on Z axis) in front of the current view:

```
this.lookAtPosition.set( 0, 0, -1 ); // -1 unit on Z (depth axis)
this.lookAtPosition.applyMatrix4( this.rotationMatrix ); // applying camera rotation to that lookat vector, so they are both the same
this.lookAtPosition.add( this.cameraWorldPosition ); // adding that vector to the camera position
```

That position is used for further calculations and is purely arbitrary, it could have been -10 or -0.5 units away from the camera, it doesn't matter, as long as it's a known position that stands in the axis of the camera. I chose '-1' so it's easier to work with.

So, we know the camera position, we now know for sure at least one point in space where the camera is looking at, and we also know the mirror position and orientation.
So now it's time to calculate the orientation of our mirrored view:

```
var target = this.mirrorWorldPosition.clone().sub( this.lookAtPosition );
target.reflect( this.normal ).negate();
target.add( this.mirrorWorldPosition );
```

First I create a target vector, which is the difference between target and mirror positions.
Then I reflect that vector along the mirror normal axis and I reverse (negate) it so I can now add it to the mirror position and I now have the final position of my mirrored target.

Finally I set up the mirror camera with correct up, target and position...

```
this.mirrorCamera.position.copy( view );
this.mirrorCamera.up = this.up;
this.mirrorCamera.lookAt( target );
```

...and proceed to the projection matrix calculations.